# Custom fields not work in python wordpress xmlrpc

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, xml-rpc

[wordpress custom field and html name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfNrC.jpg) 
this is the code:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost, GetPosts

linktest = 'http://automatication-test.local/xmlrpc.php'
loginId = '1234'
password = '1234'

wp = Client(linktest, loginId, password)
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'Episodio 1'
post.post_type = 'episode'
post.post_status = 'draft'
post.custom_fields = [{
    'key': 'kiranime_episode_number',
    'value': '1'
}]
wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

i put the name of custom field and when i load new post the field is empthy and not written 1

Answer (score 0):

Substitute with this syntax and it will work:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost, GetPosts

linktest = 'http://automatication-test.local/xmlrpc.php'
loginId = '1234'
password = '1234'

wp = Client(linktest, loginId, password)
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'Episodio 1'
post.post_type = 'episode'
post.post_status = 'draft'
post.custom_fields = []
post.custom_fields.append({
 'key': 'key_text1',
 'value': 'value_text1'
})
wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).